# TikZ - how to produce a tesselation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to produce a simple tesselation using TikZ, like the one below:

[image: Tesselation of the plane]

but have not found much success. I tried replicating some work I have seen here, but even the position of the diamonds is not what I expect:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\tikzset{pics/.cd, diamond-left/.style={code={
\path [every diamond-left/.try, #1]
 ( 0, 0) -- ( 0.866, -0.5) -- (0.866, 0.5) -- ( 0, 1) -- cycle;
}}}

\tikzset{pics/.cd, diamond-right/.style={code={
\path [every diamond-right/.try, #1]
 ( 0.866, -0.5) -- ( 1.732, 0) -- ( 1.732, 1) -- (0.866, 0.5) -- cycle;
}}}

\tikzset{pics/.cd, diamond-top/.style={code={
\path [every diamond-top/.try, #1]
 ( 0, 1 ) -- ( 0.866, 0.5) -- ( 1.732, 1) -- ( 0.866, 1.5) -- cycle;
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(300:5pt),y=(30:5pt)]
\pic at ( 0, 0) {diamond-left={fill=red}};
\pic at ( 0, 0) {diamond-right={fill=green}};
\pic at ( 0, 0) {diamond-top={fill=yellow}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code tries to produce the 3 diamonds that produce the hexagon with size 1, that produces only:

[image: Basic hexagon]

The values 0.866 is approx. \sqrt{3}/2. What is the proper way to define it?

Answer (score 8):

You can write `({sqrt(3)/2},-0.5)` or use polar coordinates `(-30:1)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
pics/diamond/.style={code={
\fill (0,0) -- ++(30:1) -- ++(150:1) -- ++(210:1) -- cycle;
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {0,...,3}{
   \pic[cyan] at ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!60!black, rotate=120] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!80!black, rotate=240] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
}
\begin{scope}[shift={({sqrt(3)/2},-1.5)}]
\foreach \n in {0,...,3}{
   \pic[cyan] at ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!60!black, rotate=120] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!80!black, rotate=240] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3)}]
\foreach \n in {0,...,3}{
   \pic[cyan] at ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!60!black, rotate=120] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!80!black, rotate=240] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) {diamond};
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D effect block tessellation]

**Edit:** 300 rows! But this code is super stupid for this. There is no need to define `pics` to do a simple fill. There is also no need to draw three shapes for every cell. -just one background for everything and then two fills for every cell. -or even just two clever fills for each row.

Anyway here is code that loops both columns and rows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
pics/diamond/.style={code={
\fill (0,0) -- ++(30:1) -- ++(150:1) -- ++(210:1) -- cycle;
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\foreach \m in {0,...,19}{
\foreach \n in {0,...,29}{
   \pic[cyan] at ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!60!black, rotate=120] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!80!black, rotate=240] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \begin{scope}[shift={({sqrt(3)/2},-1.5)}]
   \pic[cyan] at ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!60!black, rotate=120] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \pic[cyan!80!black, rotate=240] at  ({\n*sqrt(3)},{\m*3}) {diamond};
   \end{scope}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Large area with 3D effect cubes]

**Edit:** Much more efficient code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\newcommand{\N}{100}
\newcommand{\M}{50}
\clip (1,-1) rectangle ({sqrt(3)*(\N+1)},{3*\M+2});
\fill[cyan]  (1,-1) rectangle ({sqrt(3)*(\N+1)},{3*\M+2});
\foreach \m in {0,...,\M}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,\m*3)}]
\fill[cyan!80!black] (0,0) foreach \n in {0,...,\N} {-- ++(30:1) -- ++(-30:1)} -- ++(0,-1) foreach \n in {0,...,\N} {-- ++(-30:-1) -- ++(30:-1)} -- cycle;
\fill[cyan!60!black]  foreach \n in {0,...,\N} { ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) -- ++(30:1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(30:-1) -- cycle};
\begin{scope}[shift={({sqrt(3)/2},1.5)}]
\fill[cyan!80!black]  (0,0) foreach \n in {0,...,\N} {-- ++(30:1) -- ++(-30:1)} -- ++(0,-1) foreach \n in {0,...,\N} {-- ++(-30:-1) -- ++(30:-1)} -- cycle;
\fill[cyan!60!black]  foreach \n in {0,...,\N} { ({\n*sqrt(3)},0) -- ++(30:1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(30:-1) -- cycle};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Very large area with cubes]

Comment: Is it possible to loop the row repetition in any reasonable way? For example if one wants 300 rows instead of 3?

Comment: This is very nice, and to be able to understand the code evolution for more columns/rows is a real plus. Painting the background and working only on two diamonds is a speed up, but your original code or three is more generic and applies to more cases and will be more helpfull to other people looking for other tesselations.

Answer (score 4):

On attempting to simplify @hpekristiansen's code, I came to a bit different way: a pic `box` is created. It is fun to use TeX's the primitive command `\ifodd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/box/.style={code={
\fill[cyan!50] (0,0)--(30:1)--(0,1)--(150:1)--cycle;
\fill[cyan!75] (0,0)--(30:1)--(-30:1)--(0,-1)--cycle;
\fill[cyan] (0,0)--(150:1)--(210:1)--(0,-1)--cycle;
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={m=6;n=4;a=sqrt(3)/2;}]
\foreach \i[parse=true] in {0,...,(m)}
\foreach \j[parse=true] in {0,...,(n)}{
\ifodd\j
\path (\i*2*a+a,-1.5*\j) pic{box};
\else
\path (\i*2*a,-1.5*\j) pic{box};
\fi 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel
for suggesting `isodd` of TikZ/PGF. With this, the code is a kind of the following one-liner.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={m=6;n=4;a=sqrt(3)/2;}]
\foreach \i[parse=true] in {0,...,(m)}
\foreach \j[parse=true] in {0,...,(n)}
\path ({\i*2*a+isodd(\j)*a},-1.5*\j) pic{box};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Many advantages we can get with Asymptote: `size` (auto-scaling, fixed size), better accuracy, easier to creat multi-parameter `picture`, etc.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(8cm); 
picture hexPoly;
pen p=Cyan;
fill(hexPoly,(0,0)--dir(30)--(0,1)--dir(150)--cycle,p+white);
fill(hexPoly,(0,0)--dir(30)--dir(-30)--(0,-1)--cycle,p+gray);
fill(hexPoly,(0,0)--dir(150)--dir(210)--(0,-1)--cycle,p+black);

int m=30,n=30;
real a=sqrt(3)/2;
for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
if (remainder(j,2)==0)
add(shift(i*2*a+a,-1.5*j)*hexPoly);
else
add(shift(i*2*a,-1.5*j)*hexPoly);
```

Another code

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(8cm); 
picture hexPoly;
pen p=Cyan;
path diamond=(0,0)--dir(30)--(0,1)--dir(150)--cycle;
fill(hexPoly,diamond,p+white);
fill(hexPoly,rotate(120)*diamond,p+gray);
fill(hexPoly,rotate(-120)*diamond,p+black);

int m=20,n=12;
real a=sqrt(3)/2;
for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
add(shift(i*2*a+remainder(j,2)*a,-1.5*j)*hexPoly);
clip(box((0,.5),(m,-n)));
```

Comment: `\path (\i*2*a\ifodd\j+a\fi,-1.5*\j) pic{box};` should do it, too, no? (Or with PGFmath: `\i*2*a+isodd(\j)*a`)

Comment: `isodd` is convenient. Thanks for suggesting a better code. I have just updated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a completely different approach using patterns. This uses PDF/postscripts own pattern procedures and this easily creates *billions* of small boxes without delay.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{rhombus1} {\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}} {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}}{
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}} 
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{30}{1pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{1pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1pt}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1pt}}\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill}
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{rhombus2} {\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}} {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}}{
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{3pt}} 
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{2pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1pt}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{30}{1pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolar{30}{1pt}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}}\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\fill[pattern=rhombus1, pattern color=cyan!60!black] (0,0) rectangle (5,5); 
\fill[pattern=rhombus2, pattern color=cyan!30!black] (0,0) rectangle (5,5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Zoom:

[image: 3D box effect pattern]

Comment: yes, the speed of compilation is faster than mine